# Updating from Graph 4.21 to 5.9 makes the calls from ASP projects hang but not from console projects

Tags: graph-api

I have made two projects using Microsoft.Graph and it started out in version 4.21 and was working great. Then I decided to upgrade to the newest version which is 5.9 and now suddenly the web service calls that use the GraphServiceClient are just hanging.

The API project code looks like this:

```
public OnePointGraphApi(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    string[] scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
    };
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

    //WinHttpHandler winHttpHandler = new WinHttpHandler();
    //IHttpProvider httpClient = new HttpProvider(winHttpHandler, false, new Serializer());
    graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    }
public Site GetSiteBySiteId(string siteId)
{
    var site = graphClient.Sites[siteId]
                        .GetAsync().Result;
    return site;
}
```

The options and the commented out code is from when I was using version 4.21.

The project that then references the previous project is like this:

```
var sharePointGraphApi = new OnePointGraphApi(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var site = sharePointGraphApi.GetSiteBySiteId(siteId);
```

The code just hangs in the GetSiteBySiteId method and never returns. The funny thing is that if I create a simple unit test in the same solution as the API project and make the same call then it runs fine and returns the site correctly. It ALSO works if I create a new console project and do the same. It is not until I create a WebService project and call the code that it hangs. It worked fine before I upgraded from 4.21 to 5.9. Any help figuring out what is going on would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I found a solution to the problem shortly after I posted the question. I do not know why it worked in version 4.21 and not in version >5 but it seems to work fine so I will post it as an answer to my own question.

The solution is to use Task.Run around the GetAsync() call.

```
public Site GetSiteBySiteId(string siteId)
{
    var site = Task.Run(() => graphClient.Sites[siteId]
                    .GetAsync()).Result;
    return site;
}
```

Come to think of it, the problem might arise because I am not using the async/await pattern.